# Using GNU ld, how can I automatically spread my code across multiple regions?

Tags: memory, embedded, ld

I have a situation where my ROM can only occupy certain areas of memory, which are disjoint.  For example, suppose I've defined the following memory regions in my linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
  lowrom (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x5000,  LENGTH = 0x2000
  midrom (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0xD000,  LENGTH = 0x1000
  hirom  (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0xF000,  LENGTH = 0x1000
}
```

What I would like is for code to go into `lowrom` until it is full, and then for code to go into `midrom` until it is full, and then for the remaining code to go into `hirom`.

The GNU ld documentation says [The linker will not shuffle sections around to fit into the available regions.](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/ld/MEMORY.html)  So it sounds like what I want to do isn't possible.

Is there some sort of workaround?  I want to avoid having to manually choose what goes into which memory region.

(Or is there another open-source retargetable linker that does support this feature?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is straight forward way.

There is a workaround in my opinion.

Let me explain using examples.

a) Assume Code size is < 0x2000 bytes then in linker script just add lowrom as below.

MEMORY

{

lowrom (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x5000,  LENGTH = 0x2000

}

b) Assume code size is 0x2050 bytes then in linker script add lowrom and midrom.

*Note that for midrom allocate only required number of bytes*

MEMORY

{

lowrom (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x5000,  LENGTH = 0x2000

midrom (rx)           : ORIGIN = 0xD000,  LENGTH = 0x0050

}

This way you can go ahead.